# Pass data from output into a method that receives a node

Tags: java, heap, nodes

I am working on a project involving data structures that includes hash tables, heaps, and disjoint set forest. I am stuck on trying to pass the data outputted from a method that finds the similarities between 2 words by expressing its similarity as a float number. The data is stored in a hash table, but I am trying to insert it into a heap. My heap method that insert elements receives as a parameter a node that contains 2 strings for the pairs of words and a double variable that will contain the similarity value. How could I pass the data as a node so that I can inserted it into a heap. I don't know what argument to pass into the `heap.insert();` found in the main method.

HeapNode Class:

```
public class HeapNode {
     public String word0; // Strores first word
     public String word1; // Stores second word
     public double similarity; // Stores similarity value

public HeapNode(String word0, String word1, double similarity) { 
    super(); 
    this.word0 = word0; 
    this.word1 = word1; 
    this.similarity = similarity; 
}
```

Heap Class:

```
public class Heap {
    public HeapNode[] H; // Stores array of nodes into heap
    public int size; // Size of heap

public Heap(int capacity) {
    H = new HeapNode[capacity + 1]; //We need to add 1 since we’re ’wasting’ H[0] this.size = 0; 
}

public void insert (HeapNode node){// Insert nodes of similar words to heap
    size++;
    int i = size;
    while ((i>1) && H[i/2].similarity*-1 > node.similarity * -1 ){
        H[i] = H[i/2];
        i = i/2;
    }
    H[i] = node;
}
```

Main Method

```
public class Word_Test {

public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Word_Clustering hash = new Word_Clustering(929);//hash table
    Heap heap = new Heap(300); // Create heap
    hash.insert(); // Insert words from text file
    hash.wordSimilarities(); // Call method that finds similarity
    heap.insert(); // Call insertion method. 

    System.out.println( );
}
```

Output data from hash table to be stored in the heap: 
[image: Output data]

Comment: Where is the data that you need to pass to `heap.insert(...)` ? Is it returned by the `wordSimilarities` method ? If so, what is this method's return type ?

Comment: Yes, it is returned by the word similarities method and the return type is void.

Comment: You'll need to find a way of accessing the data before you can pass it to the `heap.insert(...)` function.

Comment: Like creating a variable that stores the data into nodes and then passing it to the insert method as a node argument?

Comment: Yes, that is right.